# Minecraft doesn't recognize my second controller

Tags: minecraft-legacy-console

I used to be able to have two player split screen but now it doesn't recognize the second controller when pressing start or A.

Any suggestions?

Comment: just a guess - but can you try to use the second controller as a primary one? just to check it's still functioning

Comment: See comment above, also, make sure you are playing with HDMI again, as using the regular Red-Yellow-White cables will not allow you to play splitscreen

Answer (score 1):

This happened to me  too, but rest assured I figured it out. For some reason the game turned everything in the options to off or the lowest setting. Quit your map and return to the title screen and go to options. Revert everying to default settings. There you go :)

Answer (score 0):

Also make sure that your TV supports and is set to 720p (at least). I had to check both my TV settings and my XBOX settings for 720p and 60Hz.